# What's the best way playing around a Django queryset, without having to runserver

Tags: python, django

Due to an [import error](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/124662419?noredirect=1) i get when trying to import a Django data model in a file running under my apps folder, i'm writing this post to have some help on this.
What is another way i can play around with a MyDataModel.objects.all() (doing for loops for example), without running the server and using the outputs on HTML.
What i mean is that i want, from my text editor (Sublime Text), to be able to run something like this (within my apps folder):

```
from .models import Article
all_articles = Article.objects.all()
```

Comment: I haven't tried but I don't think you'll be able to query the database from the `models` if the server isn't running. Either put your import in a `try/except` clause or copy your app to a clean project. Or disable the other apps temporarily...

Comment: Running my code over the Shell provided with Django works well. I can import my models here.
```python manage.py shell```
But this isn't my text editor and isn't convenient.

Comment: Not surprising: `python manage.py shell` runs the database for you. I could be wrong but I don't think you'll find the solution you are looking for. So, don't get stuck, work with it.